# No GRUB after trying to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 with Optane (Lenovo Yoga C940)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb

So I've tried to install Ubuntu using the 20.04 liveusb, and I can't seem to get it to boot. I'm pretty sure this is related to some sort of bootloader problem - either installed in the wrong place, or in the wrong way. I've tried:

- Reinstalling using the liveusb
- the Boot-Repair software (I didn't even -get- a "Recommended repair" button, which is weird)
- Reinstalling again using the liveusb with a different place for the bootloader

What should I try next?

Comment: Please post boot-repair pastebin and gparted screenshot

Comment: @Ajay http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/H5D6fvXnHw/ https://i.imgur.com/RI4y6M8.png

Comment: What brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? You show two NVMe drives, one small. Is that Intel RST or RAID for Windows hibernation/fast start up (only)? Add AHCI driver to Windows & change drives to AHCI in UEFI.  You are not showing Ubuntu entry in UEFI, so grub not fully installed in UEFI boot mode. Make sure Windows fast start up is off. After updates & fast start up turned off, use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. If errors post those. Be sure to only boot in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @oldfred Thank you! Brand new Lenovo C940, straight out of the packaging. I haven't updated anything, but it was also brand new. I believe that small drive (32 gb) is an Intel Optane something-or-other (~=Intel RST?). Don't see any fast start option in BIOS. I tried the button in Boot-Repair and followed the instructions and got a problem: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3bcjd7kbtG/

Secure Boot is off in the BIOS, I'm not sure how much of an effect that'd have?

Comment: It says grub installed without error and you now have an UEFI ubuntu entry. But gpt errors & lots of NTFS errors. Typically the system reserved always shows as an error, and can be ignored. But others may be fast start up related. Windows has fast start up, UEFI has fast boot setting. Best if both off when re-configuring system. Even new systems may need updates.http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation It looks like you then need gpt fixes also.

Comment: which options did you choose Install alongside Windows 10 or Something else ?

Comment: check this https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've finally found the solution after hours of looking! Turns out that the problem was indeed caused by the Optane drive included in the laptop (a Lenovo Yoga C940.)

The way to fix this was to turn off Optane entirely and switch to AHCI, first turning off Optane in Windows (using the crappy Intel app for this) to prevent data loss, and then go into the BIOS, find a little bit of blue text labeled Storage -> press right arrow key -> switch from RST to AHCI. I got a warning that it would wipe my drives, but this did not happen (others on the internet confirmed they also did not lose data.) Still, always best to backup anyway.

I also turned off Fast Startup in Windows at some point - I have no idea of the effect this may have had, but just putting it out there for anyone with the same problem. I also did not need any drivers, or to update anything, in order to change from RST to AHCI.

After doing the above, I was able to simply boot my liveusb, install Ubuntu normally with the "Install alongside Windows 10", and there I had it, a working, booting Ubuntu install.

If anyone is struggling with optane and this -doesn't- help: Good luck, you're going to need it. Here are two related links that might help (thanks kannzzmm2 for the first one):
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uXgbF3P2F8